# Отменить добавления записи в trigger before insert

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер, innodb

Есть таблица, в которую добавляются просмотры. Так вот если в таблице существует запись с этим пользователям, нужно НЕ добавлять запись а изменить существующую. Примерный код триггера:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_view
  BEFORE INSERT ON ad_views
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  SET @idExists = (SELECT ad.id FROM ad_views av WHERE av.ip_address = NEW.ip_address AND av.ad_id = NEW.ad_id);
    IF  @idExists THEN
      UPDATE ad_views av SET av.quantity = av.quantity + 1;
      //Отменить добавления текущей записи;
    ELSE
      //Все нормально, можно добавить текущий запись;
    END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: С mysql не работал, но в postgresql можно сделать так: `RETURN NULL;` - когда не надо записывать.

Comment: @aleks.andr Я попробовал так сделать, но вылетает ошибка, что RETURN разрешен только в функциях

Comment: Тогда создайте триггерную функцию, в которой будет `RETURN NULL`. Из триггера вызывайте её.

Comment: @aleks.andr В mysql-е нету триггерных функций

Comment: Повторюсь, не работал с mysql. Попробуйте [вот это решение](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850294/trigger-for-validating-url-column-values-in-mysql-table).

Comment: @aleks.andr Спасибо за ваши ответы. Попробовал сделать решения по вашей ссылке. В итоге оказалось, что триггеры в Mysql не имеют права работать с таблицей на котором они запущены. Can't update table 'ad_views' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: А нельзя ли воспользоваться конструкцией `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ?

Comment: На MySQL вы триггерами такую задачу не решите. Используйте insert on duplicate key или replace